C# MudBlazor MudTimePicker select 24:00 instead of 00:00
I am using the MudTimePicker MudBlazor for a C# Project.
I need to be able to select a Timespane from 00:00 to 24:00.
Does anyone know how i could do this with Mudblazor?
Yes, i could just interpret 00:00 as 24:00 in the "to" field but this feels more like a hack.

"24:00" does not exist. The largest HH:mm you can get is 23:59. We had that issue und added a TickBox for "whole day" and send Date/00:00 - Date+1/00:00 to the backend. (It's a little more complicated, actually, but roughly speaking, that's it)

^^ Thats Start inclusive, End _ex_clusive by convention to avoid overlaps. So a "whole day" is from 00:00 until just shy of next 00:00.

24:00 does not exist in day.
Max value/end of day: 23:59:59.9999999
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-endofday
